# Thumbnails in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, thumbnails

The Laracast regarding images is invalid for 5.3 as the upload simply becomes:

```
if ( isset($request->image) ) {$path = $request->file('image')->store('public/users');
```

This is fine and I store $path in a db. Now I want to also add a thumbnail from this so I added:

```
Image::make($request->image)->fit(200)->save()
```

but I get NotSupportedException in AbstractEncoder.php line 150: Encoding format (tmp) is not supported.

Help please!

Comment: You should use the already stored image path to make the thumbnail instead of `$request->image`.

Comment: I have added use 

    'Intervention\Image\Image' 

to the head and changed the code so I get the actual image and added this code:

    $manager = new Image();
    $file = substr(strrchr($path, '/'), 1);
    $tpath = 'public/users/thumbs/'.$file;
    $image =Image::make($tpath)->resize(100, 100);

but I get the following error:

    Call to undefined method Intervention\Image\Image::make()